# Unable to activate my Search Topology

Tags: 2016, topology, searchserviceapplication

I've been trying to use [this PS code](https://melcher.it/2012/07/sharepoint-2013-create-a-search-service-application-and-topology-with-powershell/), to set up my new Search service application.

But I'm failing at activating the SearchTopology

When `$SearchTopology.Activate()` runs it returns the following after like 3-5 min:

```
Activating new topology
Exception calling "Activate" with "0" argument(s): "Topology activation failed. "
At line:56 char:1
+ $SearchTopology.Activate()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SearchTopologyActivationException
```

Do anyone have any idea how i can fix this problem?

**Update**

If I write `$SearchTopology` in the PS, I get the following

```
TopologyId     : 5028dc75-69ac-412d-bd90-8eca44ea5716
CreationDate   : 24-08-2017 08:57:15
State          : Inactive
ComponentCount : 6
```

Don't know if it's any help but.